# Mysql trouble with like and or like

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
SELECT `id`, `name_person`, `person_content`, `datetime` 
FROM (`achievers_unverified`) 
WHERE ` name_person LIKE '%ved%' 
   OR ` person_content LIKE '%ved%' LIMIT 10
```

This is the sql query i am trying to use where ved is the search term.

i am gettin a 1064 error.

the codeigniter code generating it is.

```
$this->db->select($select)
            ->from($table)
            ->like($str[1], $query, 'both')
            ->or_like($str[2], $query, 'both')
            ->limit($offset+10, $offset);
```

this is the error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'person_content LIKE '%ved%' LIMIT 10' at line 3.

```
$str = explode(",", $select);
where $select = id, name_person, person_content, datetime
```

Comment: What exactly is in `$str[2]` and `$str[1]`?

Comment: What are the random ticks for after `WHERE` and `OR`?

Comment: I tested this with your code and do not get this result, I get the correct one. Are you 100% sure that this code is what's producing the issue, and have you tried hard-coding the values instead of using variables? What version of Codeigntier are you using?

Comment: if you analyse th sql query then you can see that ' is missing at the end of fields name near like . i inserted that in phpmyadmin and it worked . But the point is whay codeigniter is generating query like this

Comment: I understand, I tested with CI and your code worked fine for me and produced the correct query.

Comment: found the solution use trim($str[0]) and trim($str[1]) the sapce was creating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution use trim($str[0]) and trim($str[1]) the sapce was creating the problem.

Comment: Aha you are correct! When I tested your query I was using Datamapper ORM which apparently takes care of this automatically, when I tried it with straight ActiveRecord it caused the same error. Apologies for doubting you and not producing an accurate test case. So, your field names were incorrect because they had extra space characters.